# What is the best way to use aws congito in javascript/nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am building a web app where front end of plain javascript, css and html. Services are hosted(EC2) in nodejs layer connecting with database. I was looking to use aws cognito as AWS is preferred cloud solution for user management for standard functions such as signup, sign in, mfa, forgot pwd, sign out and so on. My question is: Is it good solution to build custom UI where username and pwd are accepted and sent to nodejs layer(on EC2) over https and then nodejs layer can connect to cognito via nodejs low level api from sdk to execute required functions such as signup, signin, mfa and return required data? I am not web app security expert, so please elaborate if this is not even a option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly an option but not a more secure one as you are transferring user credentials over HTTPS in both cases. You should avoid sending any user credentials to your backend. Let the frontend send user credentials to cognito and exchange it for temporary tokens. Cognito provides its own hosted GUI which handles all the standard cognito functions that you mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. For some reasons we don't want to use the hosted UI. So you are suggesting to use javascript api's provided by amplify to call cognito directly and exchange the tokens. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, let front end call cognito directly.